# Keyboard Hidden crashes on android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-softkeyboard

Does anyone solve the problem with keyboard hidden crash on android 5.0? I've tried on 4.4.2 with the same code but it doesn't happen.

This is my activity settings:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

This is the log after freezing

```
 06-17 20:43:57.823 32593-32604/org.mydev.app.debug W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.210ms
06-17 20:43:59.503 32593-32604/org.mydev.app.debug W/art: Suspending all threads took: 195.356ms
06-17 20:44:02.633 32593-931/org.mydev.app.debug E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.Object maps.W.d$c.c' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at maps.W.d.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.W.d.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.X.J.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.ac.i$d.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.ac.i.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.ac.n.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.X.A.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.X.H.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.X.H.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.X.y$f.f(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at maps.X.y$f.run(Unknown Source)
06-17 20:44:02.673 32593-32593/org.mydev.app.debug I/Choreographer: Skipped 557 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Try to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in _activity_ tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's still crashed. The App freezes and then crashes.

Comment: Can you please post crash log?

Comment: I've updated the question with the log. Please have a look :-)

Comment: In my app, there're 5 fragments in a viewpager. Two fragments contain google map. I think it the cause of this exception.

Comment: Strangely, after removing the admob view, this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

else use this method to hide the Keyboard with respect to EditText.

```
public static void hideKeyboadOnView(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            view.getWindowToken(), 0);

   /* inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);*/
}
```

and pass the edittext view in this method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". Thank you all for guiding me.